# Grails EHCache Warm up

Tags: grails, ehcache

I am using Grails 2.4 with Ehcache configuration which works fine. Now my requirement is to load all the domain objects at startup into ehcache so the further page loads are faster. My site is mostly read only and the Database can reside in memory easily. Is there a way to do this? If I load all domain objects by a query in bootstrap would that warm up the cache?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I think loading them all in Bootstrap.groovy should do the trick - but just to be sure you could install the [Melody plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/grails-melody) and inspect the contents of your cache once your app starts up.